# How to remove private dependant framework from swiftinterface file when building frameworks?

Tags: swift, frameworks

one of the mine XCframeworks has a dependent framework that is added as source code (swift) through cocoapods. I don't want to expose this framework, but when i build my XCframework, "#import xxxxxx" directive is added to the .swiftinterface file.
Is there any way to avoid adding this #import to the .swiftinterface file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use `@_implementationOnly` import, for example:

```swift
@_implementationOnly import Alamofire
```